# Extracting specific data from CSV file

Tags: python, r, csv

I am getting ready to run some machine learning classification tests on a sample set of student data. I have the data in CSV format, but I need to make some extractions and I was hoping someone could give me some advice on how to do what I need in Python or R. Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

As you can see there are four students listed and their respective grades for courses they have taken thus far. I only need to examine the students that scored a 'W' in course C5, but I also need to preserve their other  corresponding grades and courses. If a student didnt make a 'W' in course C5, all of their data can be removed.

For example: In the data above students 'C' and 'D' could be removed from the set altogether because they scored a 'B' in course C5 or didnt take it at all, but all of the other students scored a 'W' in course C5 and thus should remain in the set.

The data set is rather large and Im looking for a more accurate way than manual deletion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: define `rather large`

Comment: in excel, run a filter and dedupe to get the students, put them in a different sheet, then use vlookup to find all records belonging to these students

Comment: thats really not very large ...

Comment: it is if I was manually deleting them!

Comment: I'd say it's larger than I would want to do by hand but not large enough that efficiency is a huge issue.

Comment: do you care about the order?

Comment: no, the order doesnt matter

Comment: Could you please post your data (by copy and paste) rather than a picture of it?

Comment: To do this in R, I suggest you start here: [http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everybody else is answering in python, I'll offer three R-based alternatives:

```
dat <- data.frame(Student = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5), rep('C', 6), rep('D', 4)),
                  Course = paste0('C', c(1:5, 1:5, 1:6, 1:4)),
                  Grade = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'W', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'W', 'A',
                      'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'W', 'F', 'A', 'B'),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Base `[` Operator

```
studs <- dat$Student[ dat$Course == 'C5' & dat$Grade == 'W' ]
studs
## [1] "A" "B"
dat[dat$Student %in% studs, ]
##    Student Course Grade
## 1        A     C1     A
## 2        A     C2     B
## 3        A     C3     A
## 4        A     C4     C
## 5        A     C5     W
## 6        B     C1     B
## 7        B     C2     C
## 8        B     C3     D
## 9        B     C4     A
## 10       B     C5     W
```

#### Base `subset` Function

I don't personally use `subset` (and [some argue](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) it may not always behave as you might expect), but it reads cleanly:

```
studs <- subset(dat, Course == 'C5' & Grade == 'W')$Student
dat[dat$Student %in% studs, ]
##    Student Course Grade
## 1        A     C1     A
## 2        A     C2     B
## 3        A     C3     A
## ...
```

#### Package `dplyr`

The [Hadleyverse](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) offers the `dplyr` package w

```
dat %>%
    group_by(Student) %>%
    do(if (any((.$Course == 'C5') & (.$Grade == 'W'))) . else data.frame())
## Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
## Groups: Student
##    Student Course Grade
## 1        A     C1     A
## 2        A     C2     B
## 3        A     C3     A
## ...
```

It is likely that there is a more efficient way to do this with `dplyr`. (In fact, I'd be surprised if there weren't, since this feels rather brute-force-ish.)

#### Performance

Since you said "the dataset is rather large," I'll offer that the first (`[`) is the fastest. With this data it is about twice as fast, but with a much larger dataset I only saw difference of 20%. `dplyr` is not faster than base, and in fact is at least one order of magnitude slower (with this implementation, caveat emptor); many argue with larger data munges it is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: `[` is often faster than `dplyr` for relatively small data like this. Once you get into the hundreds of thousands of rows `dplyr` overtakes `[` (at least for straight-up filtering). Unrelatedly, I'd use `dplyr` like this: `filter(dat, Course == 'C5' & Grade == 'W') %>% select(Student) %>% left_join(dat)`

Comment: I should also add, nice answer, (+1) and way to include and explain multiple options!

Comment: @Gregor, I have wondered about that (and do not have much large-data experience with `dplyr`), so I generated a randomly-generated 12000-row dataset with this structure, and `dplyr` was two orders slower versus base `[` ... do you know under what conditions `dplyr` is faster?

Comment: I did something similar the other day, I benchmarked `filter()` vs `subset` vs `[` vs data table `[` on two columns of random normal data, testing whether `x^2 + y^2 < 0.25`. I tried with `1e3`, `1e4`, `1e5`, and `1e6` rows. I think it was at 1e5 that dplyr and data table started really kicking butt. Basically, they have more fixed overhead, so are slower for small data (when it's lightning fast however you do it so it doesn't matter), but when you get to bigger data the overhead is negligible and the efficiencies show.

Comment: Just looked at my results, at `1e6` rows, in milliseconds, `[` was 180, `subset` was 215, `filter` was `40` and `[` on a data table was 48. (Mean of 100 evaluations.) And I'd imagine the differences only get larger as the size increases from there.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). A pandas Dataframe is a data structure that is very similar to an excel sheet.

**Read CSV**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

**Filter students:**

```
filtered = df.groupby('Student')\
             .filter(lambda x: (x['Course'] == 'C5').any() and 
                               (x['Grade'] == 'W').any())
```

**Write results to disk**

```
filtered.to_csv('filtered.csv', index=None)
```

EDIT (@Anzel): Alternatively you can do:

```
df = df.set_index('student')
filtered = (df['Course'] == 'C5') & (df['Grade'] == 'W')
df.loc[list(df[filtered].index)].to_csv('filtered.csv')
```

Comment: ahh thats way easier than mine (not to mention mine was wrong)

Comment: But that only keeps the rows for C5. All the scores for the user should be kept if C5 is W.

Comment: @elyase, isn't the last line should be => `df[filtered].to_csv(...)`?

Comment: @elyase, I just realised you haven't exported all students `to_csv()`, I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: @Anzel, thanks a lot! I have corrected it and added your solution as an edit.

Comment: @elyase, not a problem! As a side note though, using filter + lambda will likely be slower than **.loc** or **.ix** methods (and more R-like). But hey OP doesn't require efficiency ;)

Comment: @Anzel, I agree and I like your solution, I just think this one reads better.

Answer (score 1):

You could scan the table twice. The first pass records the students that should stay in the dataset and the second pass does the writing. Student scores could be in any order and you would still pick them up.

```
import csv
import os

input_filename = 'my.csv'
output_filename = os.path.splitext(input_filename)[0] + '-out.csv'

with open(input_filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)
    table = [row for row in reader]

w_students = set(row[0] for row in table if row[1]=='C5' and row[2]=='W')

with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in table:
        if row[0] in w_students:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Im getting a TypeError: TypeError: splitext() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: that should have been `input_filename` I've fixed the code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - the set is only used to determine membership. The table is written in the order it is read with non-conforming students removed.

Comment: That did it - thanks to @tdelaney and everyone else that offered their assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about R and I just hate Excel, so I'll just answer in python. It's just pure Python, although elyase's answer is good if you don't mind using an external library.

The most interesting module for your case is [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html). Additionally, `collections.namedtuple` allows you to create a nice abstraction over your objects.

```
import csv
import collections

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Read the first line to get the headers
    Record = collections.namedtuple("Record", next(reader))
    # Read the rest of the file into a list
    records = [Record(*line) for line in reader]

# This will give you objects with a nice interface (fields with header
# names). For your example, you would have fields like record.Course
# and record.Grade.
```

Once you have a list of records, building a dictionary with the grades for a student is easy, especially if you use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
students = collections.defaultdict(list)
for record in records:
    students[record.Student].add(record)
```

Filtering can be done in various ways, but I like generators and all...

```
def record_filter(records):
    has_grade = False
    for r in record:
        if r.Course == 'C5' and r.Grade == 'w':
            has_grade = True
    return has_grade

filtered_students = {key: value for key, value in students
        if record_filter(value)}
```

Comment: creating a namedtuple from the header is clever - with the caveat that it won't work if there are spaces or any excluded characters in the header fields.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly something to look for. But if you are on Python 3.1+, there is an optional `rename` boolean parameter to `namedtuple`, which will skip invalid names.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different data file

```
% cat datastu.csv
1,1,1
1,2,1
2,1,1
3,2,4
3,1,2
3,3,3
4,1,3
4,2,4
5,1,0
5,2,5
%
```

and a different requirement, that is `course==2` and `grade==4`.  With these premises, this is my program

```
% cat datastu.py
# save if course == 2 and grade == 4

inf = open('datastu.csv')
data = {}
for l in inf:
    s,c,g = l.strip().split(',')
    data.setdefault(s,[])
    data[s].append((c,g))

for s in data:
    if ('2','4') in data[s]:
        for c, g in data[s]: print ','.join((s,c,g))
```

Its output is

```
3,2,4
3,1,2
3,3,3
4,1,3
4,2,4
```

I'm sure that you can easily adapt my approach to your requirements.